# Converting Smart Contracts into Arithmetic Circuits

Tags: cryptography

Are there any existing programs available to convert smart contracts into Arithmetic Circuits with which I can implement and experiment with Secure Multiparty Computation (MPC) protocols?

Comment: Software libraries are off-topic here. You can try [crypto.se].

Comment: [*Software Recommendations*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be a good fit, too.